# How to skip a file inside if statement in shell script and move to next file in the same directory?

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I had a directory with 10 files.I need to read each file one by one .If any failure while processing the file then I need to capture that  file name to send over the mail and skip the current file and move to the next file in the directory.

I tried like this

```
for test in $test_path
do 
if [ ! -s $test ];then
  echo ' failed'
fi

#other codes are here that needs to run with the above input file

done
```

Comment: Not sure what is the question here. If it's only about how to skip..in you if statement, after the echo add a "continue".

Comment: After `echo "failed"` you add `continue` on the next line.... Also, ALWAYS quote your variables in `[ ... ]`, e.g. `if [ ! -s "$test" ]; then`

Comment: Shorthand would be `[ -s "$test" ] || continue` to ensure the file exists and is non-empty OR `continue` (skip the remainder of the loop and get the next file)